# ¿Cómo evaluar varias variables y graficarlas en una sólo expresión en Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Quisiera graficar Ley de Archi esta definida de esta forma Sw=sqrt(a*Rw)/(phi**m*Rt) Donde Rw tiene valor de 1 , 2 y 3. Ahora quisiera graficarla sin tener que poner Rw[0], Rw[1], Rw[2], si no que con un tipo función me evaluara los 3 valores. Por ejemplo Sw=sqrt(a*Rw[i))/(phi**m*Rt) donde i es 1, 2 y3. Y que toda la gráficas salga en una sóla.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from pylab import *

'''
Ley de Archie

Sw=sqrt(a*Rw)/(phi**m*Rt)

pow(phi,m)=phi**m
'''
phi=np.arange(0.01, 0.4, 0.01)
Rw=np.array([0.1, 2, 3])
Rt = 2
a = 1
m = 1.7

#Declarar variable
Sw1=np.sqrt((a*Rw[0])/((phi**m) *Rt))
Sw2=np.sqrt((a*Rw[1])/((phi**m) *Rt))
Sw3=np.sqrt((a*Rw[2])/((phi**m) *Rt))


figure(1)
clf #Para cerrar pestaña

plot(phi, Sw1     )
plot(phi, Sw2     )
plot(phi, Sw3     )

xlabel('Phi')
ylabel('Sw')
legend(['Rw1','Rw2','Rw3'])
xscale('Linear')
yscale('linear')
grid('True')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Cual es la variable `Rw`??

Comment: Aquí dejo el código completo, Ya que stackoverflow me marcaba error con el código completo. https://github.com/javibash/python/blob/main/Ley

Comment: Todo el código debe ir aquí en la pregunta, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/477834/edit) tu pregunta añadiendo el código

Comment: Listo , ya me dejo subir aquí el código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza un comprensión de lista para tener todos los valores, luego la recorres y graficas.

```py
Sws =[np.sqrt((a*rw])/((phi**m) *Rt)) for rw in Rw]

for sw in Sws:
    plot(phi, sw)
#... resto del código
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias.  El código quedo de la siguiente manera. import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from pylab import *

'''
Ley de Archie

Sw=sqrt(a*Rw)/(phi**m*Rt)

pow(phi,m)=phi**m
'''
phi=np.arange(0.01, 0.4, 0.01)
Rw=np.array([0.1, 2, 3])
Rt = 2
a = 1
m = 1.7

#Declarar Rw
Rw = [numero for numero in  range(1,4)]
print(Rw)

Sws = [np.sqrt((a*rw)/((phi**m) *Rt)) for rw in Rw]

for sw in Sws:
    plot(phi, sw)